# How can I re-send an email to a donor using a system workflow message template?

Tags: email, system-workflow-messages

I am using CiviCRM 4.6.3 on D7. A number of users created PCP but lost their automated emails for PCP Supporter Welcome message and their other system generated email for one-time password creation. Need to re-send to them. How can I do this?